# Looking for an adjective

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I am looking for **an adjective to describe a pillow that is 'too high / too big /too uncomfortable' to sleep on.** Could I use 'bloated'? On the Internet, I saw some people using 'fluffy' (too fluffy) in similar context (but I don't mean a pillow covered in fluff). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: "Bloated" sounds good for me.  It is an extension of the usual meaning, so it would need context.

Comment: Thank you! In general, it is not defective; just someone doesn't like that pillow type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in your question, "fluffy" is normally a *good* attribute that people want out of a pillow. You could prefix almost any adjective with "*too*" to show that it was to an excessive degree and therefore a negative thing. It could be too big, too large, too high, too fluffy. I personally would not say "*too uncomfortable*", because that would imply that there was some level of discomfort that was acceptable for a pillow.

If you are looking for a single, negative adjective word that makes clear it is too big (but without requiring "too", you could say that the pillow is:

- Bulky
- Oversized
- Plump (although sometimes considered a good quality in a pillow)

Comment: Thank you! Great suggestions!